# deny access of php file from url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Here's the Scenario,
I have a sample link that looks like this
Let's say ProjectName/products.php

I was able to rename the URL in htaccess to make it look like: ProjectName/products

HTACCESS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products?$ products.php
```

My question is, is it possible to deny access when trying to enter URL ProjectName/products.php ? I'm new in htaccess. I've tried adding deny from all, yes it solved the problem of not accessing that php file but it happens that I also can't access now the cleaned URL, I hope i made my question clear. thanks for the help.

Comment: that won't work, because it will forbid access to everybody including the newly rewritten urls from people who legitimately entered `ProjectName/products`. On another note, I don't think it's a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To deny external access to the php file, you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /products\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```